# Cookie not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

Cookies are not working with IE.  The browser is set to allow cookies.  It works fine in Firefox... and works fine in IE when I run it locally.  But as soon as I publish, it breaks.  It is used for a poll so a user cannot vote more than once.  The following code runs once a user tries to vote:

```
if (Request.Cookies["Poll"] != null && Request.Cookies["Poll"].Value == "Voted")
{
    // Display label
    lblVoted.Visible= true;
}
else
{
    // Update DB
    // Add cookie
    Response.Cookies["Poll"].Value = "Voted";
    Response.Cookies["Poll"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have underscore in your local server name. Sometimes this can be an issue.
Check http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/bugs.asp

Answer (score 1):

If your cookie is a 3rd party cookie (e.g. in a subframe from a different origin) then the setting of the cookie would likely be blocked by P3P). Click View > Web Page Privacy Policy to see if any cookies are blocked.